# Writing a sorting algorithm from scratch in Python3.6

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, sorting

I am trying to create an original sorting algorithm for my home work for school but i can't get it to work and I don't understand why.

```
def sa(x):
    print(x)
    i = 0
    s_array = []

    while x:
        for x[i] in x:
            if x[i] == min(x):
                s_array.append(x.pop(i))
                i = 0
            elif x[i] == max(x):
                s_array.append(x.pop(i))
                i = 0
            else:
                i += 1

    print(s_array)
```

I know I shouldn't have print functions in the program but i wanted it to be concise and packaged. so this is the output i get:

```
>>> sa([89, 23, 33, 45, 10, 12, 45, 45, 45])
[89, 23, 33, 45, 10, 12, 45, 45, 45]
[89, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 12]
```

I had the code like this:

```
def sa(x):
    print(x)
    i = 0
    s_array = []

    while x:
        for x[i] in x:
            if x[i] == min(x):
                s_array.append(x.pop(i))
                i = 0
            else:
                i += 1

print(s_array)
```

but was getting this as the output and thought i had to add the max() elif:

```
>>> sa([89, 23, 33, 45, 10, 12, 45, 45, 45])
[89, 23, 33, 45, 10, 12, 45, 45, 45]
[10, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45]
```

please help.

Comment: `for x[i] in x:` is assigning `x[i]` to each element of `x` as it is iterated.  Absolutely certain that isn't what you are intending.

Comment: if i = 0 doesn't the for loop statement x[i] assume x[0]?

Comment: There is no point of a for loop and a while loop in this case. You should pick one, for sorting you probably want the while though. Also you can do, `while x: s_array.append(x.pop(x.index(min(x))))`.

Comment: thank you @StevenSummers and for helping me out. taking the for loop out and using the while loop you provided works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

the way your for loop is written you are **assigning** `x[i]` to an element in `x` according to iteration, consider this:

```
i = 0
x = ["a","b","c","d","e"]

for x[i] in x:
    print(x)
```

This will display the following:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['c', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['d', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['e', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Notice that the first element `x[0]` is changing to each element of the list as the list is iterated over, and when `i` changes it basically mixes up the elements of the list in a predictable but rarely useful way.  instead since you only want to loop while there is still elements in the list just remove the inner `for` loop:

```
while x:
    if x[i] == min(x):
        s_array.append(x.pop(i))
        i = 0
    else:
        i += 1
```